# Sorting in Mongoose doesnt work correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorting doesnt work with Mongoose, but I don't understand how this can be possible since I've searched so much! Any time I tried it didn't work. Here is my code

```
Pics.find({}).limit(8).populate('creator').sort("created_at", 1).execFind(function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
});
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Invalid sort() argument. Must be a string or object.
at Query.sort (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:755:11)
at /Users/n/Proj/feetshot/app.js:112:45
at callbacks (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
at param (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
at pass (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
at Router._dispatch (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
at Object.handle (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
at Context.next (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/n/Proj/feetshot/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/context/http/actions.js:64:8)
at SessionStrategy.pass (native)
```

How can I make sort working?

Here is my schema:

```
var PicSchema = new Schema({
creator: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }
, body: String
, created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
, link: { type: String, index: { unique: true } }
, twitter_id: { type: String, index: { unique: true } }
, tags: [String]
  , likes: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }]
   });
```

Comment: The basic structure looks okay; what does your `Pics` schema look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your error message you must be using Mongoose 3.x, however you're using the 2.x `sort` method parameter style.  Either switch to the 2.7.0 Mongoose release or change your sort usage to `sort('created_at')`.  From the 3.x source:

```
/**
* sort
*
* Sets the sort order. Accepts a single parameter, either an object or string.
* If an object is passed values allowed are 'asc', 'desc', 'ascending', 'descending', 1, -1.
* If a string is passed it must be a space delimited list of path names. The sort order of each path is ascending unless the path name is prefixed with `-` which will be treated as descending.
*
* Examples:
*
* // these are equivalent
* query.sort({ field: 'asc', test: -1 });
* query.sort('field -test');
*
* @param {Object|String}
* @api public
*/
```

Comment: I use mongoose 3. My question is how can I use desc ?

Comment: got it, but if I use the minus or I don't use it, I still get the same :S

Comment: 3.0 hasn't been released yet, so I'd stick with 2.7 unless you specifically need something in the 3.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

1. correct the sort method call using a string
2. do the sort earlier.Before the populate.

So:

```
Pics.find({}).sort("created_at").limit(8).populate('creator').execFind(function(err, docs){
    console.log(docs);
});
```